# jquery - is it better to apply a method to a set of DOM elements using filter() or each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, filtering

Let's say I have a page that shows a default set of DOM elements on page load, and once the page loads, I want to go in and hide certain elements.

### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li id="blue">BLUE</li>
        <li id="red">RED</li>
        <li id="green">GREEN</li>
        <li id="orange">ORANGE</li>
        <li id="violet">VIOLET</li>
        <li id="teal">TEAL</li>
        <li id="black">BLACK</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### JavaScript #1

```
var valid = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
var $colors = $('li');
$colors
  .hide()
  .filter(function() {
      return valid.includes(this.id);
  })
  .show();
```

### JavaScript #2

```
var valid = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
var $colors = $('li');
$colors.show();
$colors.each(function() {
    if(!valid.includes(this.id) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Assuming the "real" use case has thousands of colors, which JavaScript approach would be the more efficient?

Comment: will there also be thousands of "valids" ?

Comment: i´d rather think about `$('#red, #green, #blue').hide()`

Comment: Doesn't #2 need to do `$colors.show()` first?

Comment: There will always be less `valid`s than `$colors`

Comment: Question updated to do `$colors.show()` first

Comment: Thousands of colors? Is this a Pantone or Crayola web site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. Loop through the IDs and show them.

```
$colors.hide();
valid.forEach(id => $(`#${id}`).show());
```

Or you can create a single selector by combining all the IDs in  `valid`:

```
$colors.hide();
valid_selector = valid.map(id => `#${id}`).join(',');
$(valid_selector).show();
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your second example will be orders of magnitude quicker than the others. It's a shame jsperf.com is down to test it.

Comment: i checked the performance on jsbench.me and actually the ops first attempt seems to be the fastest